# React context api with useReducer state not changing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I have an Auth screen and a HomeScreen, and to manage the state I am using Context API in which I have 2 states -> 1) `user` state on which I'm deciding whether I am authenticated or not (while fetching info from the server), 2) `loading` state to show a loading screen when all this is happening. The problem is, everything is working, even setting the state of `user` from null to a well defined object coming from my API, and in the same way I'm changing my `loading` state but it is not changing, it is `false` everytime despite I'm dispatching using the same method.

Context file:

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import {UserReducer} from './reducers';

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  loading: false,
};

const UserContext = createContext(initialState);

export const UserProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [globalState, dispatch] = useReducer(UserReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{
      user: globalState.user,
      loading: globalState.loading,
      dispatch,
    }} >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}
```

Actions:

```js
export const SET_USER_DETAILS = (userDetails) => {
  return {
      type: 'SET_USER_DETAILS',
      payload: userDetails,
  };
};

export const SET_LOADING = (loadingState) => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_LOADING',
    payload: loadingState,
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```js
export const UserReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_DETAILS':
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case 'SET_LOADING':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Main Navigation File:

```js
const Navigation = () => {
  const {user, dispatch, loading} = useAuth();
  console.log(user); // after successful fetch from api, I'm getting the desired user data.
  console.log(loading); //  PROBLEM => always false.

  useEffect(() => {
    checkUserLoggedInStatus(dispatch);
  }, [dispatch]);

  return loading ? (
    <LoadingScreen />
  ) : !user ? (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Verify" component={OTPVerificationScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  ) : (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Message" component={MessageScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

The `checkUserLoggedInStatus` function:

```js
export const checkUserLoggedInStatus = (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(SET_LOADING(true)); // NOT WORKING/NOT CHANGING THE LOADING STATE
  AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
  .then((token) => {
    if (token) {
      fetch(`${API_URL}/user/`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          ...
        },
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.type === 'success') {
          const details = data.data.user;
          dispatch(SET_USER_DETAILS(details)); // THIS IS WORKING FINE.
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
  dispatch(SET_LOADING(false)); // NOT WORKING/NOT CHANGING THE LOADING STATE
};
```

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong because I am doing the same thing with `SET_USER_DETAILS` action/reducer function but I don't know what's wrong with the `loading` state.

SUMMARY: Not able to render `LoadingScreen` based on `loading` state from `UserContext`.

If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it!

Thank you!

Comment: you can check this how to use context live example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-usecontext-usereducer-state-management

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment, I'm using `Context API` and not `redux` although the boilerplate & concept is quite similar but still, and I know how contextAPI works because I am able to change `user` state but not the `loading` state, even though both the function are written using same method. Do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that in the `checkUserLoggedInStatus` you are setting the loading state false outside the `then` and `catch` blocks. Since you are performing asynchronous task and need to set the loading to false after this async task is completed, you need to set the loading to false in either `then` or `catch`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Just one more thing, while the state is changing, I could see my login screen for a millisecond- got an error in console, then the Loading screen and finally my authenticated screen is rendered. The error was: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method. In PhoneInput (at Login/index.js:37)` What could be causing this?